# Find the generating function for $\displaystyle \sum_{k = 0}^{\infty} x^{k^2}$

Tags: generating-functions

I've tried equating the coefficients of the rational expression below  but cannot terminate the coefficients i.e. find a finite $N$ and $M$:

$$  \sum_{k = 0}^{\infty} x^{k^2} = \frac{\displaystyle \sum_{k = 0}^{N} b_k x^k}{1 + \displaystyle \sum_{k = 1}^{M} a_k x^k}$$

$$ \left(\sum_{k = 0}^{\infty} x^{k^2} \right) \left( 1 + \displaystyle \sum_{k = 1}^{M} a_k x^k\right) = \sum_{k = 0}^{N} b_k x^k$$

Comment: What do you mean with the generating function ? And it is related to the [Jacobi theta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theta_function#Jacobi_theta_function).

Comment: user1952009 - a finite numerator and finite denominator.  It could be related to the Jacobi theta function?

Comment: It is not a rational function (the coefficients $1_{\sqrt{k} \in \mathbb{N}}$ don't satisfy a linear recurrence)

Comment: user1952009 - thanks. With each power $x^n$ two new variables are introduced $a_k$ and $b_j$, I tried to form an alternating pattern for the $a$ and $b$ coefficients which would allow the $a$ and $b$ terms  to be written in a form similar to $\frac1{1-x^2}$

Comment: :D can you show that the coefficients $c_{n^2} = 1$ , $c_n = 0$ otherwise don't satisfy a linear recurrence ?

Comment: user1952009 - I hadn't thought of a contradiction proof.

Comment: $+1-1 \dots$ patterns may be more effective.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Let $c_{k^2} = 1, c_k = 0$ otherwise.

Assume that $$\sum_{k=0}^\infty c_k x^k = \frac{\sum_{k=0}^N b_k x^k}{\sum_{k=0}^M a_k x^k}$$
Then the coefficients $c_k$ satisfy the linear recurrence
$$\sum_{m=0}^M c_{k-m} a_m = b_k \qquad \qquad (1)$$

But this is impossible, since $|(n+1)^2-n^2| \to \infty$, hence for $n > 2M$  :

$c_{n^2-m} = 0$ for $0 < m < M$, and $(1)$ for $k =  n^2$ becomes $c_{n^2}=  b_{n^2}$, a contradiction with $b_k = 0$ for $k > N$

Comment: user1952009 - I see it now, thanks.

Comment: @arthur I deleted your edit because it is buggy too much latex (but you can find it back in the history)

Answer (score 1):

$\sum_{k = 0}^{\infty} x^{k^2}
$
is a theta function:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theta_function

These functions have
many fascinating properties,
but a generating function
of the type you want
is not one of them.

Comment: marty cohen - thanks. If it did I guess some one would have found it. I didn't understand why the ratio and coefficients trick didn't work until now.