# Definite sum of a decreasing series

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, integers, sums-of-squares

can we find a closed form for following sum:

\begin{equation}
\sum_{i=0}^{n} a^{i^2} = a^0 + a^1 + a^4+a^9 +...a^{n^2}
\end{equation}

where $0<a<1$ , what if $n \rightarrow \infty$ ?

Comment: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/JacobiThetaFunctions.html

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1974533/find-the-generating-function-for-displaystyle-sum-k-0-infty-xk2

Comment: Computing the truncated theta function via Mordell integral : https://arxiv.org/pdf/1306.4081v2.pdf

Comment: A NEARLY-OPTIMAL METHOD TO COMPUTE THE
TRUNCATED THETA FUNCTION, ITS DERIVATIVES, AND
INTEGRALS : https://www.dtc.umn.edu/publications/reports/2008_06.pdf

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio thank you, so it is a Truncated Theta function, do you know any famous approximations or bound for the theta function?

Comment: @arthur thank you, I skimmed the papers you shared, it seems authors proposed numerical methods for fast evaluation of truncated theta functions, however I am looking for a approximation/bound/etc that can be written in closed form